# Second ViewController won't open properly Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, tableview

i'm having a problem where my first view controller is just repeating itself and not showing the second view controller, I've watched videos on how to pass data from one view controller to another and i have it all set up the way its supposed to be. it transfers the data to the second view controller properly and I've tested it with Printing the information I'm passing, but any other ui elements won't show up on the second view controller, i think they are being covered by the table view but it doesn't make sense to me and I'm not sure how to test this.
when i press on a table view cell its supposed to open the second view controller
this is the code that sends and presents the second view controller:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    //open another view contoller and show the recipe
    let secondvc = self.display![indexPath.row]
    let secondvcresources = secondvc.resource
    let secondvcdirections = secondvc.directions
    let secondvcname = secondvc.name
    let vc = CustomSecondViewController(resources: secondvcresources!, directions: secondvcdirections!, name: secondvcname!)
    present(vc,animated: true)
}
```

this is the second view controller:

```swift
import UIKit

class CustomSecondViewController: ViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray
        title = name.uppercased()
        let textview = UITextView()
        textview.frame = view.bounds
    }

    private let name: String
    private let directions: String
    private let resources: String

    init(resources: String, directions: String, name: String ){
        self.resources = resources
        self.directions = directions
        self.name = name

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        print(resources)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your app doesn't know under which storyboard you have your second view controller unless you explicitly tell it.

Comment: how would I explicitly tell it?

Comment: How do you define the views for your second view controller? Is its view hierarchy defined in a storyboard as Russel suggests? If so, you should create your second view controller using code like this: `let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “ CustomSecondViewController”)` (assuming you make the view controller’s identifier “CustomSecondViewController” in the storyboard.)

Answer (score -1):

Your current code doesn’t work because your `CustomSecondViewController`‘s init method,

```
init(resources:directions:name:)
```

…doesn’t do anything to load the view controller’s views. A `CustomSecondViewController` you create with that init won’t have any views, and won’t display to the screen.

If you want to load your `CustomSecondViewController`’s views from a storyboard, you need to use the function `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` to create it.

Your rewritten `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` function might look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    //open another view contoller and show the recipe
    let secondvc = self.display![indexPath.row]
    let secondvcresources = secondvc.resource
    let secondvcdirections = secondvc.directions
    let secondvcname = secondvc.name
    guard  let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “CustomSecondViewController”) else {
       fatalError(“CAn’t load view controller from storyboard”)
    }
    // you’ll need to refactor your CustomSecondViewController so it’s properties are public vars, not private “lets”
    vc.directions = secondvc.directions
    vc.resources = seconded.resources
    vc.name = secondvc.name
    present(vc,animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that im not understanding this fully, but what do you mean by refactor my second view controller?

Comment: Change it's name, resources, and directions properties from `private let` to `public var`.

Comment: i tried that but it gave me an error that said: Attribute 'public' can only be used in a non-local scope

Comment: or did you mean i do that in the second view controller code?

Comment: i tried using the instantiate way instead of calling the class but it still does the same thing, where it keeps generating the same table view as the first view controller